# Solving the following ODE using Fourier transforms

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, proof-verification, fourier-transform

I was wondering if anyone could show me how to solve this ODE using Fourier transforms only, I've tried the problem, it was a past exam question which I'm using to revise. However, we have only used Fourier transforms to solve PDE's in lectures so I'm unsure if what I'm doing is correct

$y'+4y=g(t)$ where $g(t)=0,t<0$ and $g(t)=e^{-3t},t\ge 0$

My solution follows as:

First taking Fourier transforms of both sides gives that $$\mathcal{F}(y'+4y)=\mathcal{F}(g(t))$$ $$\implies i\omega F(\omega)+4F(\omega)=\frac{1}{3+i\omega}$$ $$\implies F(\omega)(i\omega+4)=\frac{1}{3+i\omega}$$ $$\implies F(\omega)=\frac{1}{(3+i\omega)(i\omega+4)}$$

EDIT:

Now using partial fractions gives that $$\frac{1}{(3+i\omega)(i\omega+4)}=\frac{1}{3+i\omega}-\frac{1}{i\omega+4}.$$
Thus $$F(\omega)=\frac{1}{3+i\omega}-\frac{1}{i\omega+4}.$$

Now applying the inverse Fourier transforms gives that $$\mathcal{F}^{-1}(\omega)=e^{-3t}-e^{-4t}$$ $$\implies y(t)=e^{-3t}-e^{-4t}$$ is the solution to the ODE?

Do I need to use convolutions? I'm very confused  any help would be great.

Comment: You can exploit the poles at $\omega=3i$ and $\omega=4i$ and use the residue theorem, if you know it.

Comment: You mention the inverse Laplace transform. Do you per chance mean to apply the inverse Fourier transform instead? Have you worked with partial fractions?

Comment: yes i mean the inverse fourier transform, and i've used partial fractions before but not to do with fourier transforms?

Comment: You can and should edit your question with this information. What happens when you split your final expression for $F$ into two fractions and apply the inverse Fourier transform to each of the them?

Comment: I will work this out now and edit my question, thanks for the help

Comment: Hi i updated my post, i was wondering if you can tell me or not i have done it correctly?

Comment: @CarlChristian is my solution correct?

Comment: When you have a candidate solution then you should always insert it into the original equation regardless of your confidence level. This will reveal any errors. If it works, then you have solved the problem. Otherwise you have to hunt for errors.